# Does this exist - 'screwdriver gun' with cartridge to automatically load new screws?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I'm looking to do some really repetitive assembly that involves screw-driving a ton of M2 screws over and over again into threaded holes to put two plastic pieces together.

Because it's a high volume job, I want to find the right tool. I thought it would be so awesome if there was a one handed electric screwdriver of some sort that would dispense the M2 screw as I hold the button, then once it's in the threaded hole/fully dispensed a new one pops out of the gun, and I can move onto the next hole, etc.

Found some related stuff for nails obviously, which is good for woodworking but not exactly my application:

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Woodworking-decoration-chain-with-screw-gun-professional-automatic-screw-driver-decorating-tools-220V-780W-1PC/32832683890.html

Could anyone confirm if what I'm looking for exists, and point me to some example products? Also down to modify similar existing tools to suit my application if need be. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are systems. Your question made me do a search.

An interesting version is [StickScrew](https://www.pemnet.com/the-stickscrew-system/) and they do screws down to M2.

[image]

*Figure 1. The StickScrews come in sticks. These are inserted through the rear of the tool and the screw snaps off when torqued. The screws have hex heads.*

See a 30 s [StickScrew video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P4T3U6nB-RY) on YouTube.

Comment: I haven't been able to find a simple "click here to buy for X" anywhere online. Hoping I don't need to have an extended call with a sales rep only to find out it's like $600 or something...

Comment: Ah, but you have "a ton" of M2 screws. That'll be in the millions so money won't be a problem!

Comment: Haha very funny =P So is this not a standard type of tool? That seems surprising given how much repetitive high volume assembly people do with machine screws.

Comment: @JDS generally people outside of factory optimisation play a bit fast with the rules. Since this requires a pressurized air line. The device itself can ve cheap but remember you need the air line if you donr have that then you need a compresser also and so on. And frankly 600 is nothing for most high volume jobs, but ask.

Answer (score 1):

Home Depot and many hardware stores sell a variety of screw driving guns with different cartridges.

Not sure which will meet your need. [Home Depot selection her](https://www.homedepot.com/p/RIDGID-3-in-Drywall-and-Deck-Collated-Screwdriver-R6791/100646501)
[image: screw gun with screw belt]

Comment: Can these use multiple types of screws? What types?

Comment: In the link you can search for the type of screw. But I have already used drywall 2" and 1-5/8 screws.

Comment: OP has "a ton" of M2 screws. They're probably 2 mm diameter with 0.4 mm (coarse) or 0.25 mm (fine) threads. See [ISO metric screw thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_metric_screw_thread).